# A mouse stole my elevator button. How can I get it back?

Tags: luigis-mansion-3

After defeating the cook boss ghost on the 2nd floor, a mouse stole the elevator button. I understand vaguely that I have to vacuum this mouse up somehow, however, they keep hiding in a mouse hole whenever I get near. How can I retrieve the elevator button to the next area from this persistent rodent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some of the cheese you find in the dining room to lure the mouse out of its hole.

Place the cheese in front of the hole. Move away from the cheese and the mouse hole so the mouse thinks it's safe. When the mouse comes out to nibble the cheese, flash it with your flashlight.

Comment: You can also shoot it with a plunger if you can aim it. It offers more range but it's more difficult to hit.

Comment: And here I was trying to set gooigi up with full suction by the mouse hole and scaring it back thinking gooigi would get it. Thanks

Comment: The "aroma lines" drifting off the cheese chunks gave me the idea :D

Comment: I was able to figure out how to lure them out on my own, just not how to go from there

Comment: You can also smash it with a chair.